# How can I prove that $\inf\{ \sqrt[n]{a} : n \in \Bbb{N}^\ast\} = 1$?

Tags: real-analysis

How can I prove that $\inf\{ \sqrt[n]{a} : n \in \Bbb{N}^\ast\} = 1$?

$$\inf\{ \sqrt[n]{a} : n \in \Bbb{N}^\ast\}=1, \qquad\text{when $a > 1$}.$$

Even if someone doesn't want to tell me the answer itself then some guidance would be helpful.

We can clearly see that $\sqrt[n]{a}>1$  for all the possible numbers of $n$.

Since we are the taking the values of $a>1$  we can say that $b_n = \sqrt[n]{a} +1 $, $b_n > 0$.

$$a=(1+b_n)^n \quad\text{since}\quad b_n>0.$$

From Bernoulli's inequality :

\begin{align}
a=(1+b_n)^n \ge 1+nb_n
&\implies 1+b_n \ge \sqrt[n]{1+nb_n} \\
&\implies \sqrt[n]{a} \ge \sqrt[n]{1+nb_n} \\
&\implies a \ge 1+nb_n \\
&\implies \frac{a-1}{n} \ge b_n.
\end{align}

Comment: Show that, $\{\sqrt[n]{a}\}$ is decreasing sequence and converges to $1$.

Comment: It is easy to see that $\sqrt[n]{a}>1$ for all $n$. Hence $\sqrt[n]{a} = 1+b_n$ with $b_n>0$. Can you show from here, using Bernoulli's inequality, that $b_n\le \frac{a-1}n\,$?

Comment: HINT: $\inf A=c$ if and only if $c\leqslant x$ for all $x\in A$ and if $b>c$ then there is some $x\in A$ such that $x\leqslant b$.