# Proof of $\inf\{ \sqrt[n]{a} : n \in \Bbb{N}^*\} = 1 $ when $a>1$.

Tags: real-analysis

We can clearly see that $\sqrt[n]{a}>1$ for all the possible numbers of n.

Since we are the taking the values of $a>1$  we can say that $b_n = \sqrt[n]{a} +1 $, $b_n > 0$.

$a=(1+b_n)^n$  since $b_n>0$

From Bernoulli's inequallity :

$a=(1+b_n)^n \ge 1+nb_n \Rightarrow $

$1+b_n \ge \sqrt[n]{1+nb_n} \Rightarrow $

$\sqrt[n]{a} \ge \sqrt[n]{1+nb_n} \Rightarrow $

$a \ge 1+nb_n \Rightarrow$

$\frac{a-1}{n} \ge b_n$

Am I getting this right ?

Comment: You deleted [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3415534/how-can-i-prove-that-inf-sqrtna-n-in-bbbn-1) four minutes ago, and basically reposted it. Is there a reason for that? WOuldn't it be better to keep the old one going?

Comment: Because it was put on hold and i needed some answers

Comment: Yes, it was put on hold. That's not a final decision, and can be undone. That's what the whole "On hold" thing is meant for.

Comment: So , i should delete this one and get back to other one ?

Comment: Well, it's basically too late now anyways, I think. Damage already done and all that. Not that what you did is a terrible thing to do, but it isn't quite the _right_ thing, and it did make me wonder.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good except for 1) a typo: you should define $b_n = \sqrt[n]{a} - 1$, and 2) finish the proof: you've obtained
$$0 \le \sqrt[n]{a} - 1 \le \frac{a-1}{n}.$$ What should you say to conclude that $\sqrt[n]{a} \to 1$?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = 0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a}= 1$. Since $a>1$ then ((a-1)/n)  >1 so it will be $/lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{(a-1)/n)} =1$ and $\sqrt[n]{a}= 1$